# Provision Profile and Apple Keychain Services

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, keychain

Currently we are in the process of building multiple apps for the same client and for the convenience we are using a common provision profile for all the apps. etc :- com.companyname.*

However each app has a unique bundle identifier.   etc : - com.companyname.appname

Today I noticed that once we save the user name on the key chain on a one app , it appears on the another app as well. So I think this common provision is the culprit here and is there any way that we can overcome this without using different provisions ?

Answer (score 0):

For development you should also use a certificate (`.cer`) from Apple Developer Program. You create the certificate by sending your private key to Apple. After this procedure install `.cer`. For using key on several machines you need to create a `.p12`.

Once you have downloaded the Apple iPhone certificate from Apple, export it to the P12 certificate format. To do this on Mac OS:

1. Open the Keychain Access application (in the Applications/Utilities
   folder).
2. If you have not already added the certificate to Keychain, select
   File > Import. Then navigate to the certificate file (the .cer file)
   you obtained from Apple.
3. Select the Keys category in Keychain Access.
4. Select the private key associated with your iPhone Development
   Certificate. The private key is identified by the iPhone Developer: `First Name`
   `Last Name` public certificate that is paired with it.
5. Select File -> Export Items.
6. Save your key in the Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file
       format.
   You will be prompted to create a password that is used when you
   attempt to import this key on another computer.

Comment: the question is about multiple applications using same password from keychain.. and whether it is because of multiple apps using same generic bundle identifier.... what you've described is a procedure for creating the keys and certificates.. is that even relevant?